# Str to str comparison

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

Why can't I use the comparison of strings in my condition?  I'm working in Python.

myjson = list of dictionaries

```
if myjson[row]['languages'] == '' | myjson[row]['languages'] == 'english': pass
else: gen_dict['languages'].append(myjson[row]['languages'])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/jv/9_sy0bn10mbdft1bk9t14qz40000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/gc_all_del_dup.txt-395854237.266.py", line 157, in <module>
    gen_nondup(f_l)
  File "/private/var/folders/jv/9_sy0bn10mbdft1bk9t14qz40000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/gc_all_del_dup.txt-395854237.266.py", line 132, in gen_nondup
    if myjson[row]['languages'] == '' | myjson[row]['languages'] == 'english': pass
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Because `|` is bitwise OR perhaps? You may want to read the Python tutorial again, you keep running into misunderstandings about syntax..

Comment: Concern duly noted. The dictionary error was appalling, but I explained why I got tripped up on it. And I think the fix for that is more likely a cup of coffee to wake me up. As for this, not sure what's wrong with having someone point out a syntax error when I thought it was a type issue or something.

Comment: I can see that the error message is confusing, especially when it should really read: *+++ OUT OF CAFFEINE ERROR +++ REDO FROM START +++* :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `or` not `|`. `or` is the logical or， `|` is a bit operator not supported by `str`.

And I recommend using: `if myjson[row]['languages'] in ['', 'english']: pass`, it is a little quicker and easy to extend.